# Unable to Iterate over rows being inserted during AFTER INSERT trigger - MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I hope you can offer some words of wisdom on an issue i've been struggling with. I am using a MySQL 5.6 trigger to copy data during inserts into a separate table (not the one i'm inserting into).

I'm also modifying the data as it's being copied and need to compare rows within the insert to each over. Due to lack of support for "FOR EACH STATEMENT", i cannot act on the entire insert dataset while the transaction is still in progress. It appears i can only work on the current row as part of the supported FOR EACH ROW syntax.

Does anybody know a way to overcome this?

thanks!

UPDATE 18/01/18: @solarflare thanks for your answers, I looked into splitting the operation into an insert then a call to a stored procedure. It would work but it's not a path i want to go down as it breaks the atomicity of the operation. I tested the same code on PostgreSQL and it works fine.

It appears that when performing a bulk insert, an AFTER INSERT..FOR EACH ROW trigger in MySQL takes a snapshot of the table as it was before the bulk insert TXN started and allows you to query the snapshot but you cannot query the other rows of the insert (even if they have been inserted).

In postgresql this is not the case, as rows are inserted the trigger can see them, even if the transaction is not fully committed. Have you ever seen this / do you know is this a configurable param in MySQL or is it a design choice?

Comment: Can you show some code to explain better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you need to process the whole dataset of inserted rows, maybe split the process into to steps: first insert (without the trigger, or at least without the part that requires processing the whole set), then do the rest in a second step. The first insert may also be to a temporary table - which will basically give you the set for the statement, then process it from there (knowing the whole set now). That's a general way. If you can simplify that in your specific task (and if it is worth the effort) will heavily depend on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: thanks for your answers, it was a long shot question. The data needs to be compared start to finish after its inserted and i only want the trigger to happen once the last row has been inserted. PostgreSQL/Oracle support statement level triggers which is exactly what i need but i was wondering if there was a MySQL pattern/hack that could do the same thing.

Comment: As I said: split the operation. Insert it into a temporary table first, do some pre/postprocessing and then start the actual insert to the destination table. That would be the most general solution: you would have the same situation as with other databases, since you are now aware of the whole dataset (even if you use triggers now, you can read the whole set). If your specific situation has a more specific solution, a nice hack, some method to rewrite your query or to reorganize your process, or if it can be done even with triggers: we can't tell you with the amount of detail in your question.

Comment: *update to the question